# How to disable a remove statement from local.xml in Magento

Tags: layout, magento

Is it possible to disable a `<remove name="left">` statement defined in a default layout .xml file, from the local.xml file?

For example, in the checkout.xml in the `<checkout_cart_index>` section, the statement `<remove name="left"/>` is defined there, but can you disable that line from the local.xml file, so you still see the left menu on the checkout page?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

By default Magento doesn't provide an `<unremove />` tag for local.xml. However, the Layout system contains the right events, such that you can implement this yourself.  And by "yourself", I mean I've [created an experimental extension](http://alanstorm.com/magento_layout_unremove_in_local_xml) that adds such a tag.  Feedback is welcome.

Comment: Thank you Alan. Your extension is awesome and works without any problems over here. Exactly what I was searching for!

Answer (score 5):

The two ways I do this are;

1. Use Alan Storm's excellent unremove plugin above.
2. Re insert the removed block in local.xml with a new name attribute but the same alias or 'as' attribute.

The name attribute needs to be different because Magento's `<remove name="foo" />` is global - it removes all instances of `<block name="foo" />` even if they are added after the remove instruction. To re add the left column, for example;

```
<reference name="root">
  <block name="left.2" as="left" type="core/text_list">
  <!-- New left column is empty, so you'll need to add your left-column blocks into it here. -->
  </block>
</reference>
```

name="left.2" means the remove action won't kill this block, as="left" means that it will still be inserted into your template via `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('left') ?>`.

Unfortunately, your newly inserted left column is empty. So you'd have to re insert any blocks in there that you want to show as well. Making Alan Storm's plugin all the more useful, I think.

Answer (score 2):

When a block is removed it is not destroyed, only ignored. You might be able to 're-enable' it with:

```
<checkout_cart_index>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="append"><block>left</block></action>
    </reference>
</checkout_cart_index>
```

I've never used this myself and wouldn't want to, if you are making a custom theme then copy the base layout files and edit them directly just as the other answers recommend.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work. It would have been a perfect solution if it did.

Comment: Unfortunately true. It doesn't work. Any further solution this way since that time?

Comment: Yup. This is a very old answer and if it ever worked it definitely doesn't any more.

Answer (score 1):

your answer is not to disable the removal but to add it again in your local.xml

Comment: Can you give me an example of how to add a removed block again?

Comment: dig up the app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/page.xml on line 78 and see how it is added

Comment: Hmm, that doesn't seem to work, I add the block 'left' in a reference to the root, as in the page.xml, and nothing shows up, even after defining explicitly another block inside the left block, like the newsletter block, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: you have to be sure that this is done after the block is removed. easier path would be copying the layout fiel to your theme directory and remove the "remove" part from this layout file. Never forget to clear cache afterwards.

Comment: Ok, so there is no way to do this only with local.xml? Damn, I like to do these layout updates the 'right' way, with no copying of the layout .xml files, too bad.

Comment: copying them is the right way as everybody can understand what files you have affected, if you modify them only from local.xml then this quickly becomes a debugging hell for others. And yes you can do that from local.xml i just don't have the time to do that for you hence giving the hints

Answer (score -3):

Rather than trying to reconstruct the entire set of blocks, comment the remove inside the original XML. This will be less of a maintenance headache than trying to reconstruct the blocks and worrying about precedence of the XML files, etc.

Turn this

```
<remove name="left" />
```

Into

```
<!-- disabling remove because X -->
<!-- <remove name="left" /> -->
```

Comment: You would have to edit Magento Core files for this solution, which is never a good idea. You can't update your system once you have changed Core files.